# SSD disk failure, but scans show it's healthy and Windows Task Manager shows weird graph

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd

- PC: Dell 7559
- SSD: SanDisk Z400s M.2 2280 256GB.
- RAM: 8GB

It's had around 3 years of usage without any trouble.

It all started when it became extremely slow, so I ran a chkdisk, which asked me to restart. The chkdsk failed, and I was unable to boot into Windows 10.

So I used the terminal to robocopy all my data, and I did a factory reset, replacing my C drive with factory image of Windows 10.

It was still trouble starting the PC, and while running it would abruptly crash, and it was reported by firmware that its hard disk failure.

So I again, did a factory reset, and its works normally now, and I ran the same diagnostics, and it says all clean! I used the firmware diagnostics, Seagate Tools and chkdsk, all said, the hard disk is fine.

But still I see this weird graph on the Task Manager, the disk reported to be  at 95% when the write speed is 600KB/s.

It goes down eventually when I don't open any new programs, but when I open a new program, like "Photos", it goes to 100%!

I am thinking this could be a disk failure. Could any one suggest me, what I should do? Run some more tests? Replace the SSD? It's definitely not a Windows issue.

[image: Task manager]

Comment: Sounds like the SSD is failing. I would replace it.

Comment: @LPChip But how can i make sure that it is in fact failing? All the tests say it's clean, but only the windows task manager says a different story.

Comment: A diskdrive error is not always detected, but the symptoms say otherwise.

Comment: Download a product such as [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) and examine the disk S.M.A.R.T. data. Add a screenshot if you want us to have a look.

Comment: @harrymc I did as you said, and here is the screenshot of the SMART data
https://imgur.com/cTF1b3V

Comment: Replacing the SSD solved my issue, Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing your SSD is undoubtedly the savvy advice.

Anyway, you could use some S.M.A.R.T. tools to perform further testing. If you have none installed on your system, you can try [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/) - I have only used it on Linux, but it's available for many Windows versions too, including Windows 10.

The read of some S.M.A.R.T. attributes would be a good indicator of a failing disks. Usually a critical condition is associated with non-zero raw values for at least one of these attributes:

- ID: 5 - Reallocated Sectors Count
- ID: 187 - Reported Uncorrectable Errors
- ID: 188 - Command Timeout
- ID: 197 - Current Pending Sector Count
- ID: 198 - Uncorrectable Sector Count

Note that any given device supports only a set of the available attributes, so you may not find all of them reported for your SSD.

See, for reference, [S.M.A.R.T on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)

Finally, please note that it's always a matter of probability: no test can predict a disk failure with 100% accuracy.

Comment: Its also worth noting that SMART might not find a problem. Sometimes the disk controller simply doesn't detect an error, but shows the signs of the illness. It may get to a point where it get worse in a matter of seconds to the point where the drive fails completely.

Comment: Hi, i ran the Speccy, and here is the snapshot of the result, it says all good.
https://imgur.com/cTF1b3V
Do you think something is definitely wrong?

Comment: There are some Non-zero raw values in the SMART data as you said.

Comment: @LPChip do you think an Hard disk issue could sometimes disable the keyboard input? I have faced issues randomly where the keyboard stops.

Comment: In my experience, non-zero raw values for "Reallocated Sectors Count" and "Reported Uncorrectable Errors", as is your case, are signs of a failing drive, possibly with already happened data loss.

Comment: A hard disk failure can not "disable" the keyboard, but can let the system temporarily freeze, so that keyboard input appears discontinuous. If it is your case, you should probably find  a high value for disk queue in Resource Monitor.

Comment: @fra-san not entirely true. Given that a keyboard in windows uses a keyboard driver, a driver is a piece of software and software resides on your harddisk, yes it is possible that a harddisk problem can cause problems on a keyboard, but if that is the case I would expect that it remains disables, and not being temporarily happen.

Comment: @LPChip I agree. I took the OP's statement as "sometimes the keyboard stops working". So, probably, its driver is in memory already, so it's not likely a direct issue with persistent storage. Maybe something paged that takes a long time to be brought back in RAM because of a drive that's busy in managing errors and relocation ops. Cant'be sure, obviously.

Comment: @LPChip Thank you guys, i replaced my SSD, and it works like a charm!, the previous SDD was indeed faulty, after all it was 3 years old.

Answer (score 1):

You have 30 errors of type
[Reported Uncorrectable Errors](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9122):

> **Reported Uncorrectable Errors** : S.M.A.R.T. parameter indicates a number of errors that could not be recovered using hardware ECC (error-correcting code).

Meaning that 30 times a read of one or more sectors from the disk was unsuccessful.
The fact that it could not be recovered using the ECC, means a hard error of
more than one or two bad bits found in at least one word of one or more disk sectors.
This unrecoverable error means that contents have been lost for forever.

SSDs are not always reliable : Some last as long as a HDD, but some quickly fail.
When choosing a new SSD, usually the ones marked "Enterprise" are stronger
and have a longer warranty period.

**You should backup your data as soon as possible.**

Since this is presumably your system drive, you might also take a disk image
using a third-party product such as
[EaseUS Todo Backup Free](https://www.easeus.com/backup-software/tb-free.html)
or
[AOMEI Partition Assistant Professional trial](https://www.disk-partition.com/download-pro.html),
and try to migrate to a new disk. You might be lucky in that the lost
bytes were non-essential, so you could avoid re-installing Windows
from scratch.

After migration, if you are still worried about the integrity of Windows setup,
run `chkdsk` and [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html),
and if problems are found and even if they are announced fixed,
I would counsel to
[Repair Install Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html),
which might be useful in any case to assure the health of your Windows
installation.