# How safe is it to run CHKDSK /b on an SSD?

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I have a SSD drive that is going bad.  So I've run:

```
chkdisk /x/b d:
```

in an attempt to repair it by forcing the entire drive `/b` to be scanned, and remapped to bad-sectors to usable sectors.

The options `/b` and `/x` are described below and in this URL https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk

> /b - Use with NTFS only. Clears the list of bad clusters on the volume and rescans all allocated and free clusters for errors. /b includes the functionality of /r. Use this parameter after imaging a volume to a new hard disk drive.

> /r - **Locates bad sectors** and recovers readable information. The disk must be locked. /r includes the functionality of /f, with the additional analysis of physical disk errors.

> /x - Forces the volume to dismount first, if necessary. All open handles to the drive are invalidated. /x also includes the functionality of /f.

So the question I have is: **Does the `/b` option cause the drive to wear out more quickly (by relocating bad sectors)?**

My belief is that if the `/r` scan and repair bad-sectors option was used, this would be OK because only sectors that couldn't be read are `moved` to a new location and the bad-sector-list would be updated only if a new bad-sector were found.

But I'm not sure about the `/b` option.

#### Searching for answers

Other similar questions are listed below:

- [Will "chkdsk /r" scan the free area of harddisk for physical damages?](https://superuser.com/questions/1408127/will-chkdsk-r-scan-the-free-area-of-harddisk-for-physical-damages)
- [SSD disk failure, but scans show it's healthy and Windows Task Manager shows weird graph](https://superuser.com/questions/1371271/ssd-disk-failure-but-scans-show-its-healthy-and-windows-task-manager-shows-wei)
- [Cannot run chkdsk on SSD drive (WIN OS installed on it) due to I/O Device Error](https://superuser.com/questions/1677304/cannot-run-chkdsk-on-ssd-drive-win-os-installed-on-it-due-to-i-o-device-error/1698524#1698524)

#### Update

In the end, running `chkdisk /b` did not fix the drive.  The command continued to end with an error:

```
 Phase duration (User file recovery): 20.97 minutes.
An unspecified error occurred (75736e6a726e6c2e 500).
```

Comment: AFAIK, SSD controllers are *entirely* in charge of rewallocating bad clusters. Though *chkdsk* might not cause any harm, it's unlikely to help. See https://superuser.com/questions/1560377/do-bad-clusters-on-modern-as-of-2020-ssd-indicate-hardware-failure for similar questions.

Comment: If your drive is truly going bad (or simply wearing out) the only real solution here is to get your data backed up and onto a new drive as soon as possible.  The SSD controller is doing the heavy lifting, but you can certainly use chkdsk /b several times to try and recover damaged files and offload them to a better drive.  If it's just a data drive, try using a file copy utility to read and copy all files to a new source and have it skip any files that error out and THEN try running chkdsk to recover damaged data.

Comment: It says in the part you quoted *Clears the list of bad clusters on the volume and rescans all allocated and free clusters for errors. /b includes the functionality of /r. **Use this parameter after imaging a volume to a new hard disk drive.***. There is no point having a false bad cluster table, because it is the source drive's bad clusters, when you image a drive.